# Draw a frame around tap zone on the widget

Tags: android, widget, frame

I have a widget and I want to draw an orange frame around a tap zone on the widget. The frame should appear when a user tapped on the tap zone and disapper when the user releases his/her finger.

At this time I'm using separate layouts for each tap zone. Them works fine except the frame. I guess, I need to set

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focuseable="true"
```

for each layout. Also, I prepared a transparent shape drawable with orange border. But I can't find out what should I do next. How to draw the shape on the tap zone only while it's tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878817/android-layout-imageview-focused-but-doesnt-show-anything-on-screen-no-highl/5164779#5164779). I have no enough reputation to vote for [abscondment's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488033/abscondment) answer. So, could someone please to vote at his post?
As about this question,

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focuseable="true"
```

attributes are not needed. I simple created a drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:constantSize="true">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="4dp" />
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#eeffd700"
      />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

and set the drawable as a background to my tap zones, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:background="@drawable/selection_rectangle"
/>
```